# How to get counts of partial matches in R or sqldf

Tags: r

I have partial text in my data frame. How to get their count
Example:

```
t=data.frame(x=c('I want to go there','I want to go here','I don't want to go'))
```

Expected:
Since first two are partial - I want their count as 2

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. How do you define partial match?

Comment: where most of the words are same in an order

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, do you want to count how many time there are the words "I want".

```
library(stringr)
t=c('I want to go there','I want to go here',"I don't want to go")
x <- str_count(t, "I want")
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my dataset, there are many such sentences, so is there a way that I can pass a column and give a criteria wherever it matches most of the words, give count